# How can i get word meaning from system dictionary from iOS

Tags: swift

Is there any way that i can get the meaning of a word from system dictionary.
In swift.

```
class func dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm term: String) -> Bool
```

this only can know the word is in the diationary or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get the meaning of a word from the dictionary. What you can do is you can show the meanings for that **word** or **term** that you will be searching for. e.g

```
let referenceVC = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "home")
self.present(referenceVC, animated: true)
```

Change "home" with whatever term you will be searching. Also make sure you have dictionaries downloaded in your simulator.